# Not displaying a picture twice

Tags: mysql, coldfusion

I'm creating a survey where employee pictures are displayed at random and logged in user selects a name from a drop down list. My problem is getting each picture to display only once for each logged in user. Here is my current query, but I'm not sure if this will work

```
<cfquery name="questions" datasource="STecMySQL">
     SELECT DISTINCT PicID
     FROM answers
 </cfquery>
```

PS: I am using mySql and ColdFusion

Comment: That will make sure each individual PicID is only returned once in the query - is it possible to see more of the code around it to see how that is used as it's not readily apparent from this

Comment: You could just add LIMIT 1 at the end of that query

Comment: What do you mean by "display only once"? Are asking how to randomize the results or how to remove duplicates?

Answer (score 2):

With your original query, if there are more than one picture id for a user, you'll get duplicates for a user.

For example, for the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT PicID
FROM answers
```

You'll get duplicate PicIDs for UserID 1 given the following data:

```
PicID   UserID
----------------
1       1
3       1
4       2
```

You really need to apply `DISTINCT` to the user id, not the picture id. Since you can't do that with your `SELECT`, the alternative is to use `GROUP BY`, assuming you also have a UserID field:

```
SELECT PicID
FROM answers
GROUP BY UserID
```

This groups the results for each user, so you'll end up with just one picture id returned per user.

However, the value for PicID would be arbitrary for users with more than one picture. So, if you want to be explicit and only return the latest PicID for each user, you can use `MAX()` like this:

```
SELECT MAX(PicID)
FROM answers
GROUP BY UserID
```

Comment: Thank you all. I know I was a little vague however, i figured it out

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have 1 user with 1 image (instead of 1 user with many images) and you're trying to only present this user/image once per user login you could save the PicID query results to the users session and remove each row thats has been displayed. So you could do something like this:

```
<!--- [ Setup our intial query --->
<cfquery name="questions" datasource="STecMySQL">
 SELECT DISTINCT PicID
 FROM answers
</cfquery>

<!--- [ Save query to session ] --->
<cfparam name="session.questions" default="questions">

<!--- [ Display Random Image ] ---->
<cfset displayRow=randRange(0, session.questions.recordCount)>
<cfdump var="#session.questions.columnName[displayRow]#">

<!---[ Remove current row - RemoveRows( intRowIndex, intRowCount ) ] --->
<cfset _r = session.questions.RemoveRows(displayRow, 1)>
```

Comment: yes i have a recordcount later in the code. thank you all for these helpful tips. many thanks